# Code::Blocks c++ compiler does not output anything

Tags: c++, linked-list, insert, codeblocks

created a program to add nodes to a linked list but it does not output anything.

```
void Insert (int data, int position) {
    struct Node* newNode = new Node();

    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    if (position == 1) {
        newNode->next = head;
        head = newNode;
        return;
    }
    struct Node* previousNode = head;
    for(int i= 0; i<=position-2;i++)
    {
        previousNode=previousNode->next;
    }
    newNode->next = previousNode->next;
    previousNode->next=newNode;

}
```

Comment: there is no output in this code, but your compiler should produce some error message for missing declarations. Please clarify if this is all your code and what output you did expect

Comment: You'll need to provide a minimal amount of code that we can run and try it ourselves. First, you're not outputting anything; add `std::cout<<"example\n";` in the block. Make sure you are calling `Insert` in your `main()` function as well.